# Rails Devise, how to correctly nest resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here's my issue, I want to correctly nest my devise routes from :

```
user_je_session POST   /users/jes/:je_id/sign_in(.:format)
```

to :

```
user_je_session POST   /jes/:je_id/users/sign_in(.:format)
```

The objective is that my users can have multiple accounts, depending on the "je" they want to access.

there's my actual routes :

```
root to: 'pages#home'
devise_for :admins, controllers: { sessions: 'admin/sessions', registrations: 'admin/registrations' }

resources :jes, param: :nom do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions', registrations: 'users/registrations' }
end
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier to use `devise_scope`. You can customize the devise routes as you wish. Something like this might be work:

```
devise_for :admins, controllers: {
  sessions: 'admin/sessions',
  registrations: 'admin/registrations'
}
as :admin do
  # Please change to: value to your actual controller or action
  post '/jes/:je_id/users/sign_in', to: 'admin/sessions#create' 
end
```

Please read more on the documentation page.

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'll try :)